# Calculating Nested for-loops in organized fashion

Tags: c++, syntax-error, nested-loops, date-arithmetic

> The wind chill index combines the temperature and wind speed to tell us how cold the wind
>   makes it "feel." The new wind chill index (often called the “wind chill factor”) used by the US
>   and Canadian weather services is determined by iterating a model of skin temperature under
>   various wind speeds and temperatures. The results of this model may be approximated, to
>   within one degree, from the following formula.
>   windchill = round(35.74 + 0.6215 * T – 35.75 * S
>   0.16 + 0.4275 * T * S
>   0.16)
>   Where T is the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit, and S is the wind speed in miles per hour.
>   Write a program that will produce the following wind chill table. You must use a nested loop.

What am I doing wrong?

I am coming back with errors back to back to back. Thank you!

```
Wind Chill Table
Speed Temperature T
MPH 45 40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5 0 -5 -10
-----------------------------------------------------------
 5 | 42 36 31 25 19 13 7 1 -5 -11 -16 -22
10 | 40 34 27 21 15 9 3 -4 -10 -16 -22 -28
15 | 38 32 25 19 13 6 0 -7 -13 -19 -26 -32
20 | 37 30 24 17 11 4 -2 -9 -15 -22 -29 -35
25 | 36 29 23 16 9 3 -4 -11 -17 -24 -31 -37
30 | 35 28 22 15 8 1 -5 -12 -19 -26 -33 -39
35 | 35 28 21 14 7 0 -7 -14 -21 -27 -34 -41
40 | 34 27 20 13 6 -1 -8 -15 -22 -29 -36 -43
45 | 33 26 19 12 5 -2 -9 -16 -23 -30 -37 -44
50 | 33 26 19 12 4 -3 -10 -17 -24 -31 -38 -45
-----------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
int t;
int s;
  int windchill;
  //cout << setw(5) << x;

  //YOUR CODE: output the table heading (top 4 rows of table) with separate     cout stm$


//YOUR CODE: Two nested for-loops to generate speed S= 5, 10, ...,50 and
// temperature T = 45, 40, ..., -10
//in the innermost loop the windchill should be calculated and displayed

 for(t=50;t<=-10;t-5)
{

windchill = round(35.74+0.6215*t-35.75*pow(s,0.16)+0.4275*t*pow(s,0.16));

 cout << windchill;
    for(s=0;s>=50;s+5)
   {
   cout << s;


   }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which errors have you got?

Comment: prog4.cpp:24: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

If `‘cout’ was not declared in this scope` is the only error, your fix is here.

Add `using namespace std;` to the beginning of your file (after includes) *or* use `std::cout` instead of `cout`.

Comment: @AaronNettles, where exactly?